# I have a question about django models. I was creating a django model in visual studio code. It suggested me below code when I type charfield

Tags: django, django-models

```
class message(medels.Model):
   messageBody= models.CharField(_(""), max_length=1000)
```

In this code what is `_("")` this? My IDE suggested to me that. Please help me to understand it.

Comment: If you wrap code in backticks (`), it will be formatted nicely and easy to read.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`_` in Django is a convention that is used for localizing texts. It is (generally) an alias for `ugettext_lazy` . Read [Lazy translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation) in the docs for more info about it. You have to add:

```py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

for it to work. I think that it is the recommended way, so VSCode autofills it for you (Have no idea why it doesn't autofill the `import` statement).